# Laravel 8.60.0 creates a file instead of a folder/symlink when I run `php artisan storage:link`

Tags: php, linux, laravel, symlink, wsl-2

[image: Image showing what php artisan storage:link creates in my public/ directory]

So , I am working on a small project where I need to create a symlink to store file in the storage directory in laravel. I was previously working on windows where the same code was working fine but as I configured [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) and set it up in my `WSL-2` environment, I performed my ritualistic tasks of setting up the config, creating symbolic link, I am noticing a weird behavior of running the `php artisan storage:link` command where it creates a file instead of a folder in my app/public folder.

It should be a clickable folder or if not clickable, atleast my IDE should show it as a directory like that of others, i.e. like `public`, `bootstrap`, `database` folders. Is that a problem with my WSL or some internal configuration of Laravel. On double clicking this link it shows:

[image: Context menu opens on clicking the file]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created it in wsl2, windows won't regonize it as a symlink, it's a unix symlink and not a windows "symlink" that's all.

In WSL you're working inside a unix based filesystem and sharing your filesystem with windows.

Comment: Is there any solution or a work around for it?

Comment: @runtimeTerror only solution you would have is working entirely in WSL2 or entirely in Windows. Why do you need access to the symlink in Windows can you not just access the folder it's linked to?

Comment: I am not accessing the symlink inside windows. It's created inside WSL!

Comment: @runtimeTerror I understood, your question makes it sound like you want to be able to access it from Windows. That isn't possible. a symlink is just a file and depending on the OS will depend on if it shows you a file or a folder, in this case that is only accessible as a folder inside WSL2 / Unix based operating systems and nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

Its because your file its just accessible in the docker container created by sail. You cant access to it like this.

Comment: That's why I asked the question? What is the work around for it?

Comment: As I said, the system inside the docker creates the folders with a system independent of windows, maybe you should make a chmod to make it accessible in 777 by connecting to the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

**note: this is not an error or missing. it is just a behavior**

In my case the happened in Ubuntu since I had to connect my `storage/app/public`  folder to `public/storage`. at first glance, I was confused, and seemed to be an error but with some more try and fail it was correct as it is. the problem was, in Windows all our files existed in a symlink to the `public/storage` folder and from there we could delete and manipulate the file but after creating the file symlink all files are only visible in `storage/app/public` directory but can access from `public/storage folder` from the web easily.

Answer (score -1):

As a work around, created folder manually and run the command.
`sail php artisan storage:link`.

It will link
[image: here]